# Limpiar formulario despues de hacer un registro

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo una duda, como limpiar mi formulario despues de hacer el envio satisfactorio de los datos con jquery, tengo este esquema:

```
var pet = $('#main form').attr('action');
var met = $('#main form').attr('method');
  $('#main form').on('submit',function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: pet,
      type: met,
      data: $('#main form').serialize(),
      success: function(res){
        console.log(res)
      },  
      error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){
        console.log(estado)
        console.log(error)
      },
      complete: function(jqXHR,estado){
        console.log(estado)
      },
      timeout: 10000
    });});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usando un reset en el js

```js
    var pet = $('#main form').attr('action');
var met = $('#main form').attr('method');
  $('#main form').on('submit',function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: pet,
      type: met,
      data: $('#main form').serialize(),
      success: function(res){
        console.log(res)
      },  
      error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){
        console.log(estado)
        console.log(error)
      },
      complete: function(jqXHR,estado){
        console.log(estado)
      },
      timeout: 10000,
      success: function(html){
           $("#main").find('form')[0].reset(); 
        }
```

suponiendo  que el id de tu form es main...

en una modal boostrap seria

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">

</div>
```

el js iria

```js
success: function(html){
       
           $("#Modal1").find('form')[0].reset(); 
        }
```

espero que todo te sirva hasta el ej de boostrap